# VSCode Live Server Extension infinitley loading on local host

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm-live-server

Recently my live server extension on VSCode stopped working. I do not know why, but now when hitting the go-live button, I am stuck infinitely loading my localhost on port 5500. I have tried reinstalling the extension, right-clicking my index.html file and going live, and some other various stuff but nothing has worked. For some reason, it did work once out of nowhere but stopped working again when I restarted my computer. Anything helps!

Comment: Can you post any html, or js in the file you are serving? One of those might be triggering a refresh

Answer (score 1):

Turns out cypress just stopped liking port 5500 but now everything works fine going off of 8080.